# cost function including constrain on vector norm

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, matrix-factorisation

I'm playing with collaborative implementation using numpy.
As a reminder, we are given a matrix $R$ of user ratings for movies. Let's assume there are 3 users and 4 movies. The data matrix we are given has a size of $(3,4)$.  $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times r}$
If we want to explain those preference with two factor. (Let's imagine that those could be the Drama-inness and the Actionn-innes of a movie, and the liking of users for action and drama) the problem we want to solve is to find a user matrix $U$ (size $(3,2)$) and a movie matrix $F$ of size $(4,2)$ such as $U\times F^T = R$
The goal is to use gradient descent.

1. We initialize randomly $U$ and $F$
2. the cost function we use is cost(U,F,R) = $ \lVert U . F^T - R \rVert ^2$
3. at each step we update $U$ and $F$ like this :
   $U \leftarrow U - \alpha \times (U . F^T - R)\times F$ and $ F \leftarrow F - \alpha \times ( U . F^T - R).U^T$

Everything works and it converges.

Now I would like to modify and add a constrain such as every line of matrix $U$ has a $l_2$ norm of $1$.

To do that my idea is the following :
I choose 3 parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and I add a term to the cost function : $Tr((U . U^T) - I_3 ). diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3))$
this gives me $\lambda_1 \ \lVert \text{first line of}\ U \rVert + \lambda_2 . 
 \lVert \text{second line of}\ U \rVert + \lVert \lambda _3 \times \lVert \text{third line of}\ U \rVert$. So I'm happy with that.

**Now my problem is that I don't now have to do the step 3 and update U**

Could anyone help me with this step?
many thanks